# Mobius transformation without fixed points

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

Let $T$ be a Mobius transformation of the unit disk $D=\{ |z|<1 \}$ onto itself, with no fixed points. Show that there exists $s \in \partial D$ such that $T^n(z) \rightarrow s$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$, for all $z\in D$.

Comment: what are the Mobius transformations of the disk onto itself?

Comment: Meanwhile, i do not have that memorized either. The easy version is in the upper half plane, $(az+b)/(cz+d)$ where $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb R$ and $ad-bc > 0.$ You can answer my first comment by going back and forth between the upper half plane and the disk.

Comment: It may be simpler to use the upper half plane rather than the disk.  We may assume wlog that $\infty$ is a fixed point, and then the transformation is $T(z) = a z + b$.  Its iterates have an easy formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We take two cases according to whether $T$ has one fixed point or two fixed points. (Since any non-identity Mobius transformation has one or two fixed points, these cases are exhaustive.)
$$ $$
Case 1:

Suppose that $T$ has one fixed point.  Let $f(z) = z+1$.
Since all Mobius transformations with the same number of fixed points are conjugate, there exists a Mobius transformation $g$ so that 
$$T = g \circ f \circ g^{-1}.$$
The iterates of $T$ are given by $T^n = g \circ f^n \circ g^{-1}$.  Fix $z \in D$.  We claim that $T^n(z) \to g(\infty)$.  To prove so, let $w_0 = g^{-1}(z)$, and define a sequence $\{w_n\}$ recursively by $w_{n+1} = f(w_n)$.  We observe that for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $T^n(z) = g(w_n)$. By definition of $f$, $f^n(z) = z + n$.  Hence, $f^n(z) \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$.  By continuity of $g$, $g(w_n) \to g(\infty)$.  That is, $T^n(z) \to g(\infty)$.
It is immediate that $g(\infty) \in \partial D$; if it were in $\mathbb{C^*}-\overline{D}$, this would contradict continuity of $T$, whereas if it were in $D$, then this would contradict the assumption that the restriction of $T$ to $D$ has no fixed points.

$$  $$
Case 2:

Define $f$ by $f(z) = az$, where $a \in \mathbb{C} - \{0\}$ and $|a| < 1$.  Since $f$ has two fixed points (namely $0$ and $\infty$), there exists a Mobius transformation $g$ so that 
$$T = g \circ f \circ g^{-1}.$$
The iterates of $T$ are given by $T^n = g \circ f^n \circ g^{-1}$. Since $|a| < 1$, $f^n(z) \to 0$ for any $z \in \mathbb{C}$.  By a similar argument to that above, for any $z \in D$, we have $T^n(z) \to g(0)$.

Comment: For case 1, you are setting $\infty$ as your fixed point and $f= z+1$? And I guess you are you working over upper half plane instead of disk?

Comment: Yes, $f(z) = z+1$.  I have edited.

Comment: Regarding your second question, I wasn’t specifically thinking of working in $\mathbb{H}$.  I suppose one could choose the map $g$ so that it took $\mathbb{H}$ to $D$ though, as $g^{-1}(D)$ must be fixed by $f$ (which means that it must be the upper half plane or the lower half plane). In case 2, the necessity of $f$ fixing $\mathbb{H}$ is not immediate.  As I said, I was not specifically thinking of mapping from the upper half plane and then back (as I assume other commenters were); I was just using the  fact that Mobius transformations with the same number of fixed points are conjugate.